# How to reset X windows layout on WSL 2 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I use WSL 2 extensively. When my computer monitors go to sleep, the layout of the X windows from WSL can get messed up - they are half rendered offscreen, I can't move them etc.

If I go to windows graphics settings and slightly rearrange my monitors, it seems to reset/relayout all the windows in such a way that the X windows all become usable again.

My question is: is there a CLI command I can fire off (on Windows) to target the built-in Windows 10 X windows server to tell it to do this relaying out?  What is the name of the built-in X server?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm still looking for the exact mechanism but I'm 40% sure it'll go through [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://gist.github.com/alphp/78fffb6d69e5bb863c76bbfc767effda) or some other similar broadcast message – and it's probably invoked from the Windows side for its Wayland-to-RDP bridge.

Comment: *"What is the name of the built-in X server?"* - It's XWayland using Weston as the compositor with the Weston RDP backend - See the [WSLg Architecture Blog Post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/wslg-architecture/) for more details.